# Gray bar for image when posting to feed

Tags: javascript, facebook, fb.ui

When I generate a feed post using the FB.ui function I find that frequently the image I attach to the post displays as a vertical gray bar. On the other hand, if I generate my feed posts using the direct https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed url the image works 100% of the time. If I provide the Facebook Debugger it detects it as a Photo and displays the image at the bottom. When I click the 'See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL' it says that the 'Document returned no data'. I assume this is because my image is not an open graph object? I'm very much at a loss here.

Comment: difficult to tell without having the url at hand or seeing what exactly the debugger is telling you. Maybe you can provide the url or the source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was our server, it was becoming inaccessible from the outside intermittently. This was causing Facebook to cache the broken links.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to add a random parameter after the image src like http://www.yourdomain.tld/yourimage.ext?randomnumber if Facebook tried to load that image when it didn't exists it will cache a 404 error. With a random parameter, it forces Facebook to refresh your picture.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't provide a direct link to the image.

Utilize **OpenGraph** tags, e.g. share link `yourwebsite.com?image=12`. Use backend script to generate OG headers, namely: `og:image`, `og:description` (see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ for more information). This way every time someone shares the content you know what image is being displayed.

Comment: How would I use this with a FB.ui call? I have set up OpenGraph files in the past but I don't see how the picture param in a FB.ui call would even get the picture from the opengraph response.

Comment: I am bad at explaining simple concepts.